# Caliburn.Micro: How can I give ActionExecutionContext a reference to the view when executing from the ViewModel

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I'm in a situation where I need to fire some IResults from within a viewmodel, without an action from the view triggering it. If I use `Coroutine.Execute(MyActions().GetEnumerator())` then the `ActionExecutionContext` does not contain information about my view. Is there a way I can work around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your ViewModel inherits from Screen or implements IViewAware, then you have access to the instance of the View from your ViewModel. So, in the case of subclassing Screen, you would override OnViewLoaded, grab the instance of the View and use that to build up an ActionExecutionContext.